# How to compare the node data values in a Linked List?

Tags: python, linked-list, mergesort

I am trying to sort the nodes in a Linked List using mergesort. In the attached block of code, mergesort attempts to compare the data values of the two nodes "l1" and "l2" but python gives me the following error:

```
if l1.data <= l2.data:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

This is the following function that the issue is in:

```
def mergeLists(l1, l2):
   if l1 is None:
       return l2
   if l2 is None:
       return l1
   if l1.data <= l2.data:
      temp = l1
      temp.next = mergeLists(l1.next, l2)
  else:
      temp = l2
      temp.next = mergeLists(l1, l2.next)
  return temp
```

This is the my entire code for mergesort:

```
def mergeLists(l1, l2):
    if l1 is None:
        return l2
    if l2 is None:
        return l1
    if l1.data <= l2.data:
        temp = l1
        temp.next = mergeLists(l1.next, l2)
    else:
        temp = l2
        temp.next = mergeLists(l1, l2.next)
    return temp

def mergeSort(head):
    if head is None or head.next is None:
        return head
    l1, l2 = divideLists(head)
    l1 = mergeSort(l1)
    l2 = mergeSort(l2)
    head = mergeLists(l1, l2)
    return head

def divideLists(head):
    slow = head
    fast = head
    if fast:
        fast = fast.next
    while fast:
        fast = fast.next
        if fast:
            fast = fast.next
            slow = slow.next
    mid = slow.next
    slow.next = None
    return head, mid
```

If someone could tell me how I could compare the data values of the nodes so that mergesort can do its thing, I'd be grateful

Comment: I suspect you wanted your if statements to be `if l1.data is None:`, not `if l1 is None:`.  Same for `l2`.  Otherwise, you need to figure out how you created a list node where the `data` value is None.  You haven't showed us anything about creating the list here.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks. I probably would've ran into an issue with that later on

Comment: This may mean your linked list was not well built. Provide the code where you build the list on which merge sort is called.